# How to defind t as a time variable

Tags: python

```
from scipy import arange
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cos,pi,sin
fm=200
fc=500
t=np.arange(0, 5, 0.5)
y1=cos(2*pi*fc*t+(fc-fm)/fm*sin(2*pi*fm*t))
```

it just a line with value one in figure how can i defind this t as a time variable
Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do ._. why is this code wrong; what errors are occurring; is it not doing what you want? what do you want? what does this do?

Comment: It is cos wave and it just show a line in the figure so i want to know how to change t type to show the cos wave

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(np.arange(0, 5, 0.5) * 60).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

It gives you:

```
array([  0,  30,  60,  90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270], dtype='timedelta64[s]')
```

You can choose the units--`s` for seconds, `m` for minutes, etc.